# Entity Framework varchar To nVarchar

Tags: entity-framework

I have a column in the database whose datatype is `varchar` and when I issue a command using Linq as in the following example:

`context.x.columnName=="someValue"`, the generated query uses `nVarchar`. I understand that Entity Framework uses `nVarchar` for strings. I tried to use the solution to decorate the column in the entity class with `TypeName="varchar"` and it works in the above scenario.

```
[Column(TypeName="varchar")]
public string ColumnName{get;set;}
```

but when I tried to write the query the following way:

`context.x.columnName.Contains("someValue")`

the generated query still has `nVarchar`...I tried all the solutions provided but still having the issue. I tried setting the data type in the Map file and also tried to set `IsUnicode(false)`, but non of them works.

Can someone please help me figure out the solution to this problem...

I really appreciate the response...

Comment: This article explains the issue and a potential workaround. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/12/12/workaround-for-performance-with-enumerable-contains-and-non-unicode-columns-against-ef-in-net-4-0.aspx

Comment: I am using Contains method to be more like "LIKE" keyword in SQL Server. This article seems to point towards looking into a collection.

Comment: Have you tried context.x.columnName.Contains(EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode("someValue")) ?

Comment: Thanks Steve. It works great....